# Merge [tag:speech-synthesis] with [tag:text-to-speech]

Tags: feature-request, tag-merge

[text-to-speech](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech) and [speech-synthesis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-synthesis) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem similar enough to me too.  Any objections out there?

Let's give it a couple weeks, and if no one objects, let's make it happen.

---

Update: No objections from anyone, so I made this happen.  Done. :)